# Adding Dynamic Hint to Code Mirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using Code Mirror with code hint (intellisense) for Javascript Language. My question is that can I add dynamic hints (variables, function names etc.) in the code editor after its created?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you'll have to dig around in the hinting code a little bit. The easiest way is to wrap the JavaScript hint function from the distribution with your own function, that calls it and then adds a few extra custom words to the result before returning it.